# How to copy selected sheets from excel file to a new excel file created by program

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Hi everyone i have an excel file which i want to use as source for new excel files.I saw some examples that can copy all sheets,however my problem is that i want to copy only selected sheets from the source file and create new file with the selected sheets. e.g. this would be like if my main table has sheets x,y,z,c,f,g  and user selects z,f,g  i will only select these three create a new .xlsx file and put them there.Is this possible with c#? thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the selected sheets for example in VBA, The below will create a new workbook with selected sheets

```
Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")).Copy
```

In C#, you can so the same thing as

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application xlexcel;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Sheets worksheets;

        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlexcel = new Excel.Application();

        xlexcel.Visible = true;

        //~~> Open a File
        xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Sample.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true,
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

        //~~> Specify the sheets you want to copy
        String[] selectedSheets = { "a", "c", "d" };

        //~~> Set your worksheets
        worksheets = xlWorkBook.Worksheets;

        //~~>Copy it. This will create a new Excel file with selected sheets
        ((Excel.Sheets)worksheets.get_Item(selectedSheets)).Copy();

    }
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot.Thats the way i needed it. Btw if i may ask one more question;how can i close the opened Sample.xlsx after the the new excel is created

Comment: `xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);`

Comment: is it normal for it to ask to save me the changed sample.xlsx? i mean the new file is still open.

Comment: You have to change `True` to `False` which means you do not want to save it before closing. Remember we are opening the file as readonly. `xlexcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Sample.xlsx", 0, true` The `True` in this is for readonly. So when you say `xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);` you will get a `SaveAs` box. Change it to `xlWorkBook.Close(False, misValue, misValue);`

Comment: i know i asked too much but as i just understood this method copies cells that are connected to the sample.xlsx cells. which is like ='C:\[sample.xlsx]FinancingSchedule'!O266  is it possible to change sample.xlsx to newly created files name

Comment: as in C:[sample.xlsx]FinancingSchedule'!O266 is                             C:[newlycreated.xlsx]FinancingSchedule'!O266  ?

Answer (score -2):

yes it is possible in command prompt you can use copy command to copy the files from many excel sheets to single sheet
the command is c:/path of the file copy sourcefile destinationfile

thanks

Comment: that is not what i was trying to say.There is A.xlsx with 10 sheets and i want to create a copy of that sheet with different sheet combinations which are asked to users.