# excel sheet copy with c# reference and links

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I needed to copy specific sheets from a source excel file to a newly created excel  sheet with c#, and by the help of you i was able to succeed. However, there is one more problem I cannot find a solution to which goes like this.

when the selected sheets are copied to new excel file created by the program the links from cell to cell stays as it was in the source file as in `"C:[sample.xlsx]FinancingSchedule'!O266"` but i want to change it to  `"C:newlycreated.xlsx]FinancingSchedule'!O266"`.

Is there a way to do that? thanks in advance

also the previous question and code:

[How to copy selected sheets from excel file to a new excel file created by program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453843/how-to-copy-selected-sheets-from-excel-file-to-a-new-excel-file-created-by-progr)

Comment: Do a simple find and Replace in Excel formulas ;) Give it a try and if you are unable to do it then I will post the code...

Comment: Hint: THis it the VBA Code `Cells.Replace What:="Sample.xlsx", Replacement:="newlycreated.xlsx", LookAt:=xlPart,  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False,     ReplaceFormat:=False` Try and convert it to `C#`

Comment: the problem is i will not know where and with what name the new created file is saved.You can look at my code at the link i provided with my question.thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this. I have commented the code so that you shouldn't have any problem understanding it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlexcel;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBookNew;
            Excel.Sheets worksheets;

            //~~> Path to save the new file
            String NewPath = "C:\\";

            //~~> name of the newly created file
            String NewFileName = "newlycreated";

            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlexcel = new Excel.Application();

            xlexcel.Visible = true;

            //~~> Open a File
            xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Sample.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true,
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

            //~~> Specify the sheets you want to copy
            String[] selectedSheets = { "a", "c", "d" };

            //~~> Set your worksheets
            worksheets = xlWorkBook.Worksheets;

            //~~>Copy it. This will create a new Excel file with selected sheets
            ((Excel.Sheets)worksheets.get_Item(selectedSheets)).Copy();

            xlWorkBookNew = xlexcel.ActiveWorkbook;

            //~~> Save the new workbook
            xlWorkBookNew.SaveAs(NewPath + NewFileName + ".xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, 
            misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
            misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);

            //~~> Loop through the sheets of the new workbook and replace "Sample.xlsx" with "newlycreated.xlsx"
            foreach (Excel.Worksheet xlsheet in xlWorkBookNew.Sheets) 
            {
                xlsheet.Cells.Replace("Sample.xlsx", NewFileName + ".xlsx", Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole,
                Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, false, false, false);

            }

            //~~> Close and Cleanup
            xlWorkBookNew.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(false, misValue, misValue);
            xlexcel.Quit();

            releaseObject(worksheets);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBookNew);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlexcel);

        }

        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you have copied a sheet and in your newly created sheet you getting all the old sheet data layed down as it is. I mean if old sheet data was started displaying from cellB1, newly created sheet is also starting its data from cellB1. If this is the case than you have to read the old sheet data cell by cell and have to explicity tell the new sheet which cell data (from old sheet) goes in which cell (newly created sheet).
copying sheet is quite simple and much faster but if you really in need of changing the positioning of newly created sheet data than you need to keep in mind the performance issue particularly in case of copying huge amount of data.
If you are really interested in this approach I can provide you the code example.
Regards,